# How can I make a test standard connected account of Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to make a test standard connected account with OAuth or onboarding flow with stripe.
With onboarding, I can make a test account successfully, but I can't make it with OAuth in stripe.
An account made with OAuth has not an email, so I can't get email from it (acc_...).
Why is this? I am so confused about it? I am not sure if it will be working on live mode.
Someone tells me you can skip the form for the test account, so I did, why I can't see the email of standard connected account in the dashboard.
I am very thankful of any advice from yours.

Comment: I want to send an invoice with connected account from stripe, i think its possible to use on_behalf_of, but I don't care to get any money to my platforms for the connected accounts. how can i send an invoice for the connected accounts? with oauth I can get secret key of connected account then it seems possible, but onboarding flow is not supposed to provide secret key. to use direct charge for invoice, I have to use customers of connected account...

Comment: You should probably reach out to Stripe support for help with this: https://support.stripe.com/contact

Comment: Thank you Paul, I will.